# Multiple PIs; different VNC appearance

Tags: vnc, desktop

I have three Rasperberry PIs but thescaling in VNC is different.  Two were identical and large enough to work on from my windows 10 (64bit) monitor.  All of a sudden (fast fingers I guess) one Pi’s scaling got really small and i cannot seem to change it.  I adjust a variety of congig,txt items and changed the PI resolution but i cannot get it back to where it ws.  Since i still have one PI scaled correctly, i do not think it’s a VNC issue (using RealVNC) but i cannot find anything on the PI itself.

I’d be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: You didn't provide much information, such as: Are all the Pi's configured exactly the same? Are they all using RealVNC? are you using VNC to connect to the Pi console, or to virtual VNC desktops?

Comment: So you have both good and bad VNC configs. Why don't you compare them?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified your Distro - however, if you run the command

```
sudo raspi-config
```

it should open up a window that you can change the configuration on.  From there go to

7) Advanced Options

A5) Resolution

Then choose what you think would work best.  You can even do this from Putty.

I had an issue with my VNC where it wouldn't show the screen at all.  For some reason, the Raspberry Pi 4 didn't work out of the box with it when the Pi 3 did with the exact same configuration.  Changing from the default resolution did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Never used Windows 10, but RealVNC viewer on macOS has a menu which pops down from the title bar which is used to change scaling etc. It also shows properties.

On the Pi (via `ssh` or direct) `tvservice -s` will show what resolution it is actually using.